# SQL query hangs in Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, select

```
select 'RATION ALL WITH CILQ' OM,
       a.p_no,
       b.rank_name,
       a.name,
       a.u_name,
       e.pa_code,
       d.descr,
       e.value,
       a.u_code,
       c.u_name,
       c.pay_grp,
       f.TRADE_ABBR,
       A.G_CODE,
       a.runing_pay,
       A.COMP
  from pj_pay_mas1       a,
       pj_rank           b,
       pj_unit           c,
       pj_payall         d,
       pj_perm_all_dedu1 e,
       PJ_TRADE          F
 where a.u_code = c.u_code
   and a.rank_code = b.rank_code
   and a.p_no = e.p_no
   and d.pa_code = e.pa_code
   and e.pa_code like '102%'
   AND nvl(A.TRADE_CODE, '000') = F.TRADE_CODE
   and a.stat_code = '01'
   and a.u_code = '21033'
   and a.p_no in (SELECT x.P_NO
                    FROM PJ_PERM_ALL_DEDU1 x
                   WHERE A.P_NO = x.P_NO
                     AND x.PA_CODE like '105%'
                     AND X.VALUE > 0)
   AND SUBSTR(E.PA_CODE, 6, 1) NOT IN ('2')
   AND E.VALUE > 0
```

I am using this simple query but it hangs on my local pc with local database. But same query execute perfect when databse is on linux. Meaning when I used to connect with linux it works perfect. But when toad with my local db it hangs and shows no response.

Why is this?

Comment: While your query "hangs", find out in another session on the same instance what your hanging session is doing. Find out the sid of your hanging session and query dictionary views like v$session, v$session_wait, v$sess_io and more.

Comment: It isn't clear to me if there is one DB or two. If two, is the data identical, are the schemas the (including indexes) the same, and are the execution plans the same? How much data is there and how comparable are the environments, in terms of CPU etc.?

Comment: Aside from potential differences in schemas/machines, please stop using the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause), and prefer explicitly listed `JOIN` conditions.  Selecting data based on only a portion of a key (`pa_code`) usually indicates you're relying on meta information, and that your data isn't sufficiently normalized - it's best to avoid this sort of situation.

Comment: i am telling about 2 diff environments. 1 db is on linux server and one is on window server. schemas are same on both.. same query execute perfect on linux server with 1 to 5 secs but when it execute on windows its hanging. Everything is same on both sides.

Comment: It can't really hang as far as I can see, so have you left it to complete and it just takes a long time (and how long)? What are the execution plans for both of them?

Comment: It takes 5 to 10 minutes for this single query.. There are more than 70 queries which are same like this and running on linux server. gives output with in 1 minute..

Comment: And what are the execution plans on the two instances, preferably with statistics? It's either getting a different plan (schemas are different, or the stats aren't up to date, or something else), and/or the performance of the two boxes is vastly different. At a guess the subquery is being handled differently, but the execution plans will tell you what is going on. Not much point us trying to guess.